# Can anyone explain this two line briefly?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Comment: What in particular is unclear about it?

Comment: It reads an `int` from system in.

Comment: Technically it doesn't read an `int`, it reads a `String` which is then converted to an `int`.  If the `String` typed in is not a valid number then an exception would be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

The line above creates a new input reader.

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

`br.readLine()` reads a string input from the user. `Integer.parseInt()` converts the string input to an integer, and then after that, it is stored in the variable `t`.

That's pretty much it. Perhaps you could tell us what is it in particular that you don't understand?

Comment: Thank you got that point on what I am actually asking about.